# How can I combine two stored procedures?

Tags: sql

I have one problem here....please help me.

I have a table called `Master_BoxStock` and I created a stored procedure like this:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE Master_BoxStock
    SET currentQty = currentQty - @insertQty
    WHERE boxName = @newBoxName
END
```

After that I want to take the result, update it again like this:

```
UPDATE Master_BoxStock
SET currentQty = Result
WHERE warehouseName = 'Display'
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: what is Result that you set to currentQty ? and why cant you have a single procedure?

Comment: I want to get updated result which is "currentQty" after @insertQty deducted and I don't know how to make it in one procedure...that's why maybe...can you show me?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the syntax I would say you are using SQL Server.
If I'm correct, you can use the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause:

```
DECLARE @Output as table 
(
    currentQty int -- (I'm guessing the data type here....)
)

UPDATE Master_BoxStock
SET currentQty = currentQty - @insertQty
OUTPUT Inserted.currentQty INTO @Output 
WHERE boxName = @newBoxName

UPDATE m
SET currentQty = o.currentQty
FROM Master_BoxStock m
CROSS JOIN @Output o
WHERE warehouseName = 'Display'
```

**Note:**
I've used cross join assuming your first update only effects one row. If that's not the case, you'll get multiple rows in the table variable and will have to add to the table variable also the row identifier so that you will know what row to pick.